# My dog growls at me occasionally when I come back from being out for long periods

Tags: dogs, training, large-dogs

My Dobermann and I have a really good relationship. He goes to my partner for play and to me for emotional regulation and cuddles. Whenever I go away for long periods of time or whenever his routine is broken in a way, and I come back home or he comes back home (from being away from my partner) he now takes like 10-15 minutes to warm up to me.

If I approach him first he will growl and his hairs will be raised, like a back off warning, and he will do this a couple of times. But then 10-15 minutes later he is back to hugging me, cuddling me and letting me do anything as per usual.

I find this so strange and am wondering what’s happening? Has he forgotten who I am, is there some sort of trigger/anger towards me because I left?

Comment: Our dog does the same thing with my dad, but I still don't know why or how to avoid this, so I cannot give you an answer. Your dog hasn't forgotten you, that much is clear. I suggest you sit or kneel down and let your dog approach you instead of you approaching your dog when he's clearly weary of you.